# WordPress not load static files

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel, polylang

Today after installed PolyLang plugin,my wordpress site has a issue:

```
err_too_many_redirects
```

so I followed some tutorials to midfield the .htaccess file in cPanel:

before:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteRule ^$ https://www.ohyanlawgroup.com/home/ [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On 
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ohyanlawgroup.com/$1 [R,L]
```

after:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ohyanlawgroup.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ohyanlawgroup.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Now the err_too_many_redirects gone.
But the website can only load part of its content, it seems all the static file has not been loaded.

Any friend can help?

Comment: Are you using Cloudflare's [Flexible SSL](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-End-to-end-HTTPS-with-Cloudflare-Part-3-SSL-options#h_4e0d1a7c-eb71-4204-9e22-9d3ef9ef7fef) option?

Comment: yes,there is a folder under file manager named ssl

Comment: What is your hosting provider?

Comment: https://gracecomputer.net/  cpanel ,I'm not sure ,this is my friend's website ,it seem's the host is a taiwan company

Comment: How did you setup your HTTPS site? Did you setup as HTTP site first?

Comment: Sorry I didn't set up this website I'm very new to wordpress and php.

Comment: Why did you remove the .htaccess lines?

Comment: RewriteRule ^$ https://www.ohyanlawgroup.com/home/ [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On 
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.ohyanlawgroup.com/$1 [R,L]

Comment: These are another different rewrite rules. What are they for?

Comment: I'm not sure I think maybe this is the error made by the plugin

Comment: I cannot put everything together. Please help me to help. Can you please edit your question to show the complete before and complete after .htaccess setup? I believe this comment should belong there somewhere, right?

Comment: Thank you so much and what I have posted now ,is the complete before and complete after.

Comment: It's still the same as before. Have you save your edit yet?

Comment: The code inside <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> </IfModule> is all the same.the only different from before and after is,after I have removed all the code outside the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> </IfModule>

Comment: Why did you remove them?

Comment: I have modified my code, please check, this code is following some tutorial

Comment: _“it seems all the static file has not been loaded.”_ - so what errors do those requests cause then - still “too many redirects” for those, or something different?

Comment: The order of things is definitively wrong here - the external HTTPS rewrite should happen _before_ all the WP internal stuff.

Comment: And checking `%{HTTPS} !on` and `%{SERVER_PORT} 80` both achieve pretty much the same thing, but the rules that follow each of those conditions use the exact same pattern, so only the first of those will ever happen. And on that you are completely discarding the original URL path.